# DisplayWecpofUI() missing

Tags: mdriven

I tried the example in the CapableObjects document "Doing MVC with CapableObjects – a white paper in 4 parts" (http://www.new.capableobjects.com/xdownloads/Doing%20MVC%20with%20CapableObjects.pdf).
Most of it worked as described, but when I came to part 3 I could not modify the file Edit.cshtml. "**@Html.DisplayWecpofUI()**" causes an error.

EDIT: I searched for „DisplayWecpofUI“ in the Object Explorer... it doesn’t exist...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wecpof enclosed the whole application including the main menu. This has subsequently been redesigned and is now part of the MDriven Turnkey product offering.

With [MDriven Turnkey](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/MDriven_Turnkey_Sessions) you provide model at the minimum. The Viewmodels in the model may be tagged as [MVC or angular](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/MVC). You can inject your own model based code into turnkey with [codedress](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/CodeDress), and [styles and fashion with css](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/MDriven_turnkey_Face_-_theme_-_styles_-_fashion) and [view overrides](https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Turnkey_session_9:_View_Override).

Comment: Is there any possibility to get this functionality without using Turnkey, i.e. automatically render views without relying on Turnkey?

Comment: Yes - enough functionality is in Eco.MVC - please look here https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Render_MVC_ViewModel_without_turnkey